# XSLT-Last node of child to be removed or inserted based on the condtions-How it can be achieved

Tags: xml, xslt

Given Input

```
<Parent status="success">
  <Child id="1" name="chi">
    <grandchild id="316" selected="0" />
    <grandchild id="317" selected="2" />
    <grandchild id="318" selected="0" />
    <grandchild id="319" selected="0" />
    <grandchild id="320" selected="2" />
  </Child>
```

required output for scenario one

if anyone of node(except last node,always selected would be 2) has attribute selected = '2' 
we should have as same as input

expected output

```
<Parent status="success">
  <Child id="1" name="chi">
    <grandchild id="316" selected="0" />
    <grandchild id="317" selected="2" />
    <grandchild id="318" selected="0" />
    <grandchild id="319" selected="0" />
    <grandchild id="320" selected="2" />
  </Child>
 </Parent>
```

required output for scenario two
if the input is as below

```
<Parent status="success">
    <Child id="1" name="chi">
        <grandchild id="316" selected="0" />
        <grandchild id="317" selected="0" />
        <grandchild id="318" selected="0" />
        <grandchild id="319" selected="0" />
        <grandchild id="320" selected="2" />
    </Child>
</Parent>
```

required output should be

```
<Parent status="success">
  <Child id="1" name="chi">
    <grandchild id="316" selected="0" />
    <grandchild id="317" selected="0" />
    <grandchild id="318" selected="0" />
    <grandchild id="319" selected="0" />
  </Child>
</Parent>
```

how we can achieve this XSL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you could restate your requirements as:

> remove the last grandchild if any other grandchild has a `selected`
>   attribute with the value of 2

which is easily achieved by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="grandchild[last()][not(preceding-sibling::grandchild/@selected=2)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Great ,It is working fine ,i am new to xml - xml xslt and not sure how to use preceding-sibling stuff.can you please share documents to learn deeply

Comment: @VinothKumar I am afraid I am not a good source for learning materials.